# Trying to just hover menu item and not entire height of the menu and my border-bottom is not occupying entire width

Tags: html, css

Im doing a menu with submenus but Im having two issues that I dont know how to solve.

**First issue** is that, when I hover my menu items, I want a gray background hover my menu item, but I dont want that this background occupy entire menu height. I just want a background above my menu link.

**Second issue**, is that Im giving a border-bottom to my `dropDownMenu li ul li`, but this border does not occupy the entire width of my li ul li element. As you can see in my fiddle.

```
.dropDownMenu li ul li {
    width: 305px;
    border-bottom:4px solid red;
}
```

Here I have what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/jcak/Lmc4mj2u/3/

In this image you can see my two issues, first my gray background occupying entire menu height.
And second behind  "Html", "CSS" and "JS" my border-bottom is not occupying entire width.

[image]

This is my html:

```
<section id="menu-container">   
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul class="dropDownMenu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">JS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Programming</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">FLEX</a></li>   
                    <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
```

And my css:

```
*
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:none;
}
#menu-container
{
    width:100%;
    height:62px;
    float:left;
    background:#4f4383;
    z-index:7;
    float:left;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;
}

#menu
{
    width:960px;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}

.dropDownMenu li ul li ul {
    list-style: none;
}


.dropDownMenu a {
    line-height: 62px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    float: left;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ccc;
}
.dropDownMenu a:hover {
    background-color:#ccc;height:62px; color:#2F3083; line-height:62px;border-radius:7px; 
}
.dropDownMenu li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}


.dropDownMenu li ul {
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    left: -10px;
    z-index: 999;

}
.dropDownMenu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 62px;
    margin-left: 10px;

}
.dropDownMenu li ul li {
    width: 305px;
    border-bottom:4px solid red;
}
.dropDownMenu li ul li a {
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 !important;
    width: 100%;
    background: #4f4383;
    border-right:3px solid #ccc;
    border-left:3px solid #ccc;
}



.dropDownMenu li ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none !important;
    left: 240px;
    top: -30px;
    z-index: 999;
}
.dropDownMenu li ul li:hover ul {
    display: block !important;
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}
.dropDownMenu li ul li ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 305px;
    display: block;
}
.dropDownMenu li ul li ul li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 !important;
    width: 100%;
    background: #4f4383;
    border-right:3px solid #ccc;
    border-left:3px solid #ccc;
    border-right:3px solid #ccc;
    border-top:3px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue 1**
Make the distinction between the link/a elements and its containing li's, so the hover state of li should affect only the background color of the a element within it.

If you want the link over the entire height, you would need to add an element like span within the a element, have the a element span the entire height, and specify the hover state to change background color of that span.

**Issue 2**
You need box-sizing:border-box. Otherwise, the border attribute ignores the padding portion of elements.

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/taruckus/Lmc4mj2u/10/

```
*
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:none;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Taruckus! Your answer fix my second issue. Dont have any idea how can I solve my first?

Comment: Thanks Taruckus, your solution works fine! But Im here trying to do also what you said, using <span>. But Im having a problem, I want my background a bit taller and wider than the link, So Im using padding:5px on mouse hover, and I have the background height and width that I want. But my when I hover my menu items they are moving, do you see some way to fix this? You can see here what Im having: http://jsfiddle.net/jcak/Lmc4mj2u/11/